# How to center list tags inside an unordered list?

Tags: html, css

How can list tags that are given a display:block and are floated left, be centered inside an unordered list.

The HTML:

```
        <div id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>About Us</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
                <li>News</li>
                <li>Events</li>
                <li>Video</li>
                <li>Photos</li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- navigation -->
```

The CSS:

```
#navigation {
    border: 3px solid orange;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#navigation ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}
#navigation ul li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 8px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of display:block, use this :

```
#navigation ul li {
    display:-moz-inline-stack; 
    display:inline-block; 
    zoom:1; 
    *display:inline;
    padding: 10px 8px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: This works well, but two questions:

1. Is this compatible on all major browsers?

2. It creates a small margin between the list items, any way to get rid of that.

Comment: sure. just add margin to your #navigation ul : say
margin:10px;

Comment: note that you can also add margin to your li, should fix the gap problem in  IE

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned. I made my comments after trying to add margin: 0 to my li style - doesn't get rid of the margins. If you run the code in firefox or IE 8 the margin problem is present. In IE 7 there are no extra margins. I want it to be that way (like IE 7) for the other browsers as well.

I just don't understand why the lists have extra margins when none were added in the css.